# EL1008E: Property or field 'content' cannot be found on object of type 'java.util.ArrayList' - maybe not public or not valid?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I trying to make simple filter for my project(phonebook) to be able to find users contacts by their email instead of id. When I simply lauch the URL: http://localhost:8080/home/phonebook. I get the following error.

**The error message**

> org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception
>   evaluating SpringEL expression: "data.content" (template:
>   "/home/phonebook" - line 29, col 13)
>
> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:
>   Property or field 'content' cannot be found on object of type
>   'java.util.ArrayList' - maybe not public or not valid?

**HomeController**

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/home/phonebook"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showPage(Model model, @RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") int page){
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        User user = userService.findUserByEmail(auth.getName());
        model.addAttribute("data",phonebookRepository.findAllByUserEmail(user.getEmail(),PageRequest.of(page,10)));
        model.addAttribute("currentPage",page);
        return "/home/phonebook";
    }
```

**Phonebook.html**

```
<tr th:each="phonebook :${data.content}">
        <td th:text="${phonebook.id}"></td>
        <td th:text="${phonebook.surname}"></td>
        <td th:text="${phonebook.firstname}"></td>
        <td th:text="${phonebook.phoneNumber}"></td>
        <td>
            <a th:href="@{delete/(id=${phonebook.id})}" class="btn btn-danger delBtn">Delete</a>
            <a th:href="@{findOne/(id=${phonebook.id})}" class="btn btn-primary eBtn">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
        <hr/>
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li class="nav-item" th:each="i: ${#numbers.sequence(0,data.totalPages-1)}">
                <a th:href="@{/home/phonebook(page=${i})}" th:text="${i}" class="nav-link"
                   th:classappend="${currentPage}==${i}?'active':''"></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

**PhonebookRepository**

```
@Repository("phonebookRepository")
public interface PhonebookRepository extends JpaRepository<Phonebook,Integer> {
    List<Phonebook> findAllByUserEmail(String email, Pageable pageable);
}
```

**SecurityConfig**

```
@Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
                .usersByUsernameQuery("select email, password, active from users where email=?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select u.email, r.role from users u inner join user_role ur on(u.user_id=ur.user_id) inner join role r on(ur.role_id=r.role_id) where u.email=?")
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

    }
```

**UPDATE 1**

Made changes to `<tr th:each="phonebook :${data}">` and i think it fixes it but i got a new error;

> org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception
>   evaluating SpringEL expression:
>   "#numbers.sequence(0,data.totalPages-1)" (template: "/home/phonebook"
>   - line 42, col 38)
>
> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:
>   Property or field 'totalPages' cannot be found on object of type
>   'java.util.ArrayList' - maybe not public or not valid?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change

`<tr th:each="phonebook : ${data.content}">`

to

`<tr th:each="phonebook : ${data}">`

Because you want to iterate the query list result,but `data.content` is just a property.

Comment: I think it works but i can't say for sure because of a new error

Comment: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#numbers.sequence(0,data.totalPages-1)" (template: "/home/phonebook" - line 42, col 38)

Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'totalPages' cannot be found on object of type 'java.util.ArrayList' - maybe not public or not valid?

I updated my post so you can check up phonebook.html

Comment: @Ekera `data` is an `ArrayList`,it doesn't have the property `totalPages`,so in your code `<li class="nav-item" th:each="i: ${#numbers.sequence(0,data.totalPages-1)}">` it's wrong,you need to rewrite it

Comment: have you solved that problem with the arraylist not public or not valid?

Answer (score 0):

`data.content` is just a property, loop through `$data` instead