# Creating ArrayList through Form submitting ( Thymeleaf + Spring MVC )

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

i wanted to know, how Lists are getting binded in Spring...and how to access them in Thymeleaf.
With and without WrapperClass
How could achieve adding single / multiple objects through an form to an ArrayList or normal Array..

I would be very thankful for an explanation.

Thats what i have tried:
Form

```html
<form action="#" th:action="@{/tests}" th:object="${features}" method="post">



        <input type="text" th:field="*{featureArrayList[0].name}"/>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{featureArrayList[1].name}"/>




    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
</form>
```

Wrapper Class

```java
  ArrayList<Feature> featureArrayList = new ArrayList<Feature>();

    public FeatureWrapper() {

    }

    public ArrayList<Feature> getFeatureArrayList() {
        return featureArrayList;
    }

    public void setFeatureArrayList(ArrayList<Feature> featureArrayList) {
        this.featureArrayList = featureArrayList;
    }
```

Model:

```java
   private String name;

    public Feature(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Feature() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
```

Controller

```java
      @GetMapping("/tests")
    public String showForm(Model model)
    {
        FeatureWrapper featureWrapper = new FeatureWrapper();

        model.addAttribute("features",  featureWrapper);
        return "Feature";
    }
    @PostMapping("/tests")
    public String proceedForm(@ModelAttribute("features") FeatureWrapper features,Model model)
    {
       for(Feature feature: features.getFeatureArrayList())
       {
           System.out.println(feature.getName());
           System.out.println(features.getFeatureArrayList().size());
       }

        return "Feature";
    }
```

Edit1:
Now its working with an Wrapper Class and using static Indexes...
How would i achieve this without a wrapper class , i read much about the EL expression **${var.index}** , but how is this working ? 
And how should i use this to dynamically add my Objects.
Edit2: Now im able to add single objects , and multiple objects to the list, but im not using any EL Expression, so i wanted to know 
when would i need to use something like this:

```html
 <div th:each="feature,stat:*{featureArrayList}">
        <input  id="myInput" type="text" th:field="*{featureArrayList[__${stat.index}__].name}"/>
    </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EL1008E: Property or field 'content' cannot be found on object of type 'java.util.ArrayList' - maybe not public or not valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50799171/el1008e-property-or-field-content-cannot-be-found-on-object-of-type-java-uti)

Comment: As far as I know, you can't bind to a list without a wrapper class.  It just doesn't work that way.

Comment: @Metroids Thanks for you answer, do you maybe know when to use the el expression i mentioned

Answer (score 1):

1. As far as I know, you can't bind to a list without a wrapper class (as stated in comments).
2. In normal Thymeleaf expressions, you can directly use variables as indexes.  Expressions like this for example:

   ```
   <th:block th:with="i=0">
       <span th:text="${array[i]}" />
   </th:block>
   ```

   However, th:field expressions are different.  If you read the section on [dynamic fields](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#dynamic-fields):

   > The problem is that Spring EL does not evaluate variables inside array index brackets, so when executing the above expression we would obtain an error telling us that `rows[rowStat.index]` (instead of `rows[0]`, `rows[1]`, etc) is not a valid position in the rows collection. That’s why preprocessing is needed here.

   So, when you are using `th:field` to bind inputs to arrays, you must use preprocessing which is why you see expressions like this:

   ```
   <input type="text" th:field="*{featureArrayList[__${stat.index}__].name}"/>
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, finally i understood the usecase.